# JTable reading empty value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, h2, numberformatexception

I have a H2 database, and I want to read records from a `JTable` to populate the database tables. However my table can have empty records.

I'm using this method:

```
     String descr = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
```

And I'm getting this error each time a field in `JTable` (i, 1) is empty:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException.
```

Any suggestions how to read and store empty values from table without this error?

EDIT: 
For more explicit example, anytime i do jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1) in a empty field, same null exception occurs..

```
     for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {

            int processos = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());

            String descr = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
            if(!descr.isEmpty())
                 descr = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString(); 
            else{ 
                 descr= "";
                        }
            //String data = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
            System.out.println(processos + descr);

            try {
                databaseManager.saveTable(intIDinternto, processos, descr, "aaaa");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

SOLUTION: Use object first, then parse to string and compare.

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        String description = " ";
            int processos = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());

            Object descr = jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1);
            if (descr!= null)
                 description = jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1).toString(); 
            else
              description = ".";

            //String data = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
            System.out.println(processos + description);

            try {
                databaseManager.saveTable(intIDinternto, processos, description, "aaaa");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `if(!jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).isEmpty())
String descr = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
else{//do Stuff
}`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i think you do not understood my question. I want to store in a string a empty value, to send to the database.
However, doing the method jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString() cannot be empty.

Comment: and exactly that you do in your else method. `if(!jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).isEmpty()) String descr = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString(); else{ String descr=new String();}`

Comment: Same problem, null exception when i do jtable.getValue(i, 1).isEmpty().
 @XtremeBaumer Check my new comment pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a check for example :

```
String descr = jt.getValueAt(0, 1).toString();
int storedValue = 0;

//check if your value is a correct integer or not
if (descr.matches("\\d+")) {
    storedValue = Integer.parseInt(descr);

} else {
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
System.out.println(storedValue);
```

The idea : check your value is correct number or not using regex `descr.matches("\\d+")` if the input is correct then you can parse it else you can't, you have to throw an exception or any thing else

Comment: Your answer is wrong because doing the method String descr = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();, the Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException. is launched .
Cant do any further verification.

Comment: check my edit @rew1nd you have to check your input before you parse it

Comment: pls @YCF_L check my new commentary.

Comment: what did you mean @rew1nd ?

Comment: pls check my edit on the inital post bro.
This String descr = jt.getValueAt(0, 1).toString(); immediately launche nullpointerexception

Comment: @rew1nd The your error is somewhere else in your code which you haven't provided, probably in the `toString` implementation of what ever object is at `0x1`

Comment: @rew1nd in fact your solution is not 100% safe `int processos = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());` what if `jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString()` is empty or not contain just integers, in this case you will get the same error `java.lang.NumberFormatException` so to avoid that, you have to check it with my answer